# Recvfrom: wait for full message (variable size message, thread)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, udp, winsock

I have a UDP client that is sending messages to a server, at a specified rate. The rate needs to be constant, so I decided to try to do my receiving of replies in a separate thread to avoid blocking or delaying on `recvfrom()`. Is it at all possible to 'wait' for a full message before receiving? What would be the best strategy to go about doing this?

```
while (true)
{
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    if (recvfrom(threadSock, ReceiveBuf, BufLength, 0, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Thread Receive failed with error %ld\n", GetLastError());
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reply received: %s\n\n", ReceiveBuf);
    }
    memset(ReceiveBuf, '\0', BufLength);
}
```

Above is my receiving code. Currently, only the first 8 characters of a reply are being read into the buffer (the buffer is 512 bytes).

How can I wait for a full message (bearing in mind the message lengths are variable).

Is this even possible? Perhaps there is a better approach.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should clarify the prints are for testing only. They won't be in the final result, as printing from a thread gives weird inline prints.

Comment: How do you know that you only got 8 bytes? You don't evaluate the number of bytes received.

Comment: Breakpoints :) It's all WIP

Comment: It's unlikely that you only get 8 bytes, iif more were sent.

Comment: My char array is populated in the first 8 elements following recvfrom. The reply that is received should be the message + an 8 byte length and 8 byte, which is also printed by my server, and the length is usually 40+ bytes depending on the incoming data.

Comment: UDP knows how much you sent, and sends it as a datagram, and receives it as a datagram. What you send and what you receive is 1::1, barring the receive buffer being too small, and barring datagram losses of course, and repetitions, and sequence errors. There is nothing here to show the contrary.

Comment: Thank you for actual information rather than accusations and dismissal @EJP I didn't realise recvfrom always waiting for a full datagram. I'll check why my server is printing the full reply but only sending a part of it.

Comment: _accusations and dismissal_?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The recvfrom function receives a datagram and stores the source address.
>
> For message-oriented sockets, data is extracted from the first enqueued message, up to the size of the buffer specified. If the datagram or message is larger than the buffer specified, the buffer is filled with the first part of the datagram, and recvfrom generates the error WSAEMSGSIZE. For unreliable protocols (for example, UDP) the excess data is lost. For UDP if the packet received contains no data (empty), the return value from the recvfrom function function is zero.

Thus, you can't receive a part of the incoming message, the receive returns only when the OS can process and return an enqueued datagram.

Comment: Totally unnecessary. UDP preserves message boundaries.

Comment: @EJP, I misread the OP's question, I though he wanted multiple message buffering. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this @DanielTrugman . Seems I failed to remember that UDP packets were sent as wholes and didn't consider the possibility that my server simply wasn't sending the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, and the small chance anyone suffering from similar confusion finds this, solution follows:

Yes, it was a silly question, I should've realised recvfrom waits for a full datagram. The problem was with my server.

It was an issue of the server not sending the full data. I'm not sure as to the exact cause, but to fix it I converted the `char*` my reply was being stored to (and printing correctly) to a `char[]`, which, when sent, worked fine.